# A generalization of Waring's problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty.$$
Is it true that there always exist two integers $K$ and $R$ (depend on $f(x)$), such that every positive integer $n$ can be expressed as $$n=r+\sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i),$$
where $|r|\leq R,k\leq K,x_i(i\leq k)\in \mathbb N.$

This is a generalization of [Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem). If $f(x)=x^2$ then $K=4,R=0.$

Comment: Alright, it's Thursday afternoon in California. I've left a pretty complete answer. Take a look, even if you've seen the first part that I posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure anyone knows. Hilbert's proof of finiteness of $g(k)$ in Waring's problem depended on the particular shape of the polynomials, namely $f(x) = x^k.$ See [CONJECTURE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tur%C3%A1n_conjecture_on_additive_bases). If you have access to a university mathematics library, look up Additive Number Theory and then Additive Bases on MathSciNet and see what happens. Meanwhile, the book you should be reading is *The Hardy-Littlewood Method* by Robert C. Vaughan. Your  trick of adding or subtracting bounded $r$ does not change things all that much.

Meanwhile, you should have little trouble settling the case of $$ f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c $$ for positive integer $a,$ by multiplying through by $4a,$ completing the square, and using the Four Square Theorem you quote. After that try $$ f(x) = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d $$ and see if you get anywhere at all, and decide what restrictions you might want on $a,b,c,d$ to make an approachable problem.

Continuing on the theme of nobody knowing in this generality, see [SCHNIRELMANN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnirelmann_density). Although your sets are strongly related to the sets for the Waring problem, they still have density zero.

Note that there is a probabilistic argument that suggests your scheme ought to work. Your polynomial starts $a x^k + b x^{k-1} + \cdots.$ As a result, the count of nonnegative $x$ values with $f(x) \leq N$ for some positive $N$ is asymptotically $N^{1/k},$ since $a^{1/k}$ goes to 1. As  a result, the sum of $k+1$ different copies gives you an excess of lattice points. So, if you can rule out $p$-adic restrictions, you can sort of expect that not many numbers will be missed, and these can be covered by your finite $r.$ Just remember that the $p$-adic restrictions are by far the major component in $g(4)$ being as large as it is. Furthermore, there are other types of obstruction. For integer $x,y,z$ and (positive) prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ we have $$ x^2 + y^2 + z^9 \neq 216 p^3.  $$ Note that the exponent 9 is not a typo.